# Why we use ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(), instead we can use unset() in php?

Tags: php, arrayaccess

Why we use **ArrayAccess::offsetUnset()** instead i hope **unset()** is enough to use. But php.net stated that:

> Note: This method will not be called when type-casting to (unset)

Can anyone tell how we use it, whether it automatically unset the called offset element from the class that implements **ArrayAccess** interface ?

Reference link http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetunset.php.

Thanks !!!

Comment: I saw this question asked about 10 times in the last 24 hours... Any reason why this suddenly is so popular? Some exam question?

Comment: No my final year project that is almost 80% depends on the **ArrayAccess** interface. So need to understand all its methods. Thanks

Comment: Why ask [when you can check](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a68603aa8233103e1537c28264ea41d3f820320)

Comment: Also casting to unset and calling unset are not the same thing. casting to unset is basically setting something to null.

Comment: @apokryfos Nitpick: “casting to unset” is basically just producing a `null` value, it doesn’t really *set* anything to anything.

Comment: I know, so when value is unset the null is generated. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `offsetUnset()` method is called, when the array access expression is used in the `unset()` function like this:

```
unset($yourSpecialObject['abc']);
```

However it is not called in the following statements:

```
$yourSpecialObject['abc'] = null;         // offsetSet() is called instead
$yourSpecialObject['abc'] = (unset)'abc'; // offsetSet() is called instead
(unset)$yourSpecialObject['abc'];         // offsetGet() is called instead
```

Comment: Thank you so much i got you. But one question arise in my mind that i know about the type casting, but what does **unset** casting do ? As i simply know that **unset()** simply unset the variable. But what does **(unset)** type casting do ?

Comment: @MummyDaddy Nothing really. It’s quite nonsensical. It just produces `null`, it doesn’t actually unset anything.

Comment: Ok you mean that **(unset)** type cast the value to **null** as its name represents. So type casting to **unset** means to **null** it. Because destroying variable along its value using **unset()** and type casting to **unset** are two abstract logics.